# How to install certificate before UAC prompt in Inno Setup?

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup, digital-signature, uac

I have a batch (.bat) file which install the digital signature into the client's `LocalMachine\Root` so that compiled exe from Inno Setup will not get the the unknown publisher prompt from Windows UAC while launching the setup.

[image]

If anyhow we could run the batch file itself from the compiled exe, right after installation begin then the unknown publisher prompt will not show.

Answer (score 1):

*You cannot mean this seriously.*

*If this were possible, what would the certificate check be for, if anyone could bypass it by installing its own certificate?*

The certificate check happens even before your installer is actually executed. You have (rightfully) no control whatsoever over this.

---

*You need to obtain a code-signing certificate signed by a trusted authority.*